# Radio input and alert in Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, alert, tabular

I need some help. 
I have program that changes table values based on user input in radio box
similar to this page:

[clicky](http://icc-cricket.yahoo.net/match_zone/odi_predictor.php)

But the problem is I want users to select the radio input only once; if they select another 
radio then values of tables get messed up. 
So what I want to know is how can I make an alert box when user selects the radio input twice?

Similar to this website [clicky](http://icc-cricket.yahoo.net/match_zone/odi_predictor.php) try clicking radio button twice and alert popsup.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: I've given a possible solution below, but I think the whole idea of preventing changes is pretty unfriendly from the user's point of view. If they work their way through all the questions and then make a mistake on the last one they have to restart the process from the beginning? Yuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity in my example I'm assuming that the id of each radio button is a combination of the name and value attributes. In addition to what I've given you below you will need to add a reset() function of some kind that sets `selectedValues = {};` and deselects all radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="A" id="group1A" onclick="radioClicked(this);" />First option
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="B" id="group1B" onclick="radioClicked(this);" />Second option

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="A" id="group2A" onclick="radioClicked(this);" />First option
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="B" id="group2B" onclick="radioClicked(this);" />Second option

var selectedValues = {};

function radioClicked(rb) {
  if (selectedValues[rb.name] === undefined) {
    selectedValues[rb.name] = rb.value;
    doTableProcessing();
  }
  else {
    alert("You can't change the selected values");
    document.getElementById(rb.name + selectedValues[rb.name]).checked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome nnnnnn but how can i add two functions to onclick
please can you give me example
i have this code 
<input type="radio" name="43" value="csk" onclick="newValues('ai');" />

Comment: For the particular case you are trying to implement you don't want to add two functions to onclick, because you only want the second function to happen if a value hadn't previously been selected. See in my example where it says `doTableProcessing();`? That was just a placeholder for you to link to your existing code so put your function call there. Having said that, if you want to call multiple functions directly from onclick you just say `onclick="function1(); function2(); function3();"`.

Comment: this is what i have nnnnnn
http://jsfiddle.net/n9jSy/3/

can you edit that page and save it  and post the link please:pray:

Comment: i have multiple radio buttons and diffrent values for functions
so i have to declare them in onclick only :(

Comment: My example works for the problem you asked about, but I'm too lazy to try to figure out how to fit it in with your code - sorry, but I'm not going to do it for you. I will give you a hint to help fix your HTML though: radio buttons function as a group when they have the same `name`: at the moment your example has all radios on the page as one big group because they all have the same `name`. See how I did two groups of two radio buttons in my example. Also note that I pass 'this' to my radioClicked function not a hardcoded string, so that the function can access all the attributes of the radio.

Comment: Just saw your latest comment. This is no problem, just add a second parameter to the radioClicked function like this: `function radioClicked(rb, callback)` which you reference in onclick as `onclick="radioClicked(this, myFunctionName);"`. Where 'myFunctionName' will be different for each radio button. Then at the point within radioClicked where you want to call your own (variable) function you just say `callback();`. For more info use Google to learn about how to pass JavaScript functions as parameters.

Comment: nnnnnnn
i have tried that but im not getting both of them to work please help

Comment: and i have fixed the radio name attribute also thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to prevent an event on a radio button input node without bringing in help from outside libraries. A simple solution is to just disable the buttons from within an onclick function attached to each input node. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/c73Mh/ . If they still need to be able to select the radio buttons for whatever reason, you can cancel the selection by selecting the button that was initially selected from within that same function. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much chris 
i have alerady on onclick function named newvalues(); attached to it 
how can i can put both function in it please tell me
what i have now is <input type=radio onclick="newvalues()" />

please reply chris